# URLConnection.getContentLength() returns -1

Tags: android

I have a URL which, when I enter in browser, opens the image perfectly. But when I try the following code, I get getContentLength() as -1:

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// determine the image size and allocate a buffer
int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();
```

Please guide me what can be the reason behind this?

Comment: You won't always have a ContentLength, for example in the case of a streaming service; also, the server might not send it. You can't depend on the content length being present.

Comment: @dmon I need byte[] of that data(image). If I don't have the size, then please guide me how can I get byte[] out of that?

Comment: That's a bad idea. Memory in Android is quite constrained, and you shouldn't be allocating huge byte arrays. Instead, you should be streaming the response to disk and reading the image from there (and resizing as necessary).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the server is sending down the response using [Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), you will not be able to pre-calculate the size.  The response is streamed, and you'll just have to allocate a buffer to store the image until the stream is complete.  Note that you should only do this if you can guarantee that the image is small enough to fit into memory.  Streaming the response to flash storage is a pretty reasonable option if the image may be large.

In-memory solution:

```
private static final int READ_SIZE = 16384;

byte[] imageBuf;
if (-1 == contentLength) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[READ_SIZE];
    int bufferLeft = buf.length;
    int offset = 0;
    int result = 0;
    outer: do {
        while (bufferLeft > 0) {
            result = is.read(buf, offset, bufferLeft);
            if (result < 0) {
                // we're done
                break outer;
            }
            offset += result;
            bufferLeft -= result;
         }
         // resize
         bufferLeft = READ_SIZE;
         int newSize = buf.length + READ_SIZE;
         byte[] newBuf = new byte[newSize];
         System.arraycopy(buf, 0, newBuf, 0, buf.length);
         buf = newBuf;
     } while (true);
     imageBuf = new byte[offset];
     System.arraycopy(buf, 0, imageBuf, 0, offset);
 } else { // download using the simple method
```

In theory, if the Http client presents itself as HTTP 1.0, most servers will switch back to non-streaming mode, but I don't believe this is a possibility for URLConnection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need byte[] of that data(image). If I don't have the size, then please guide me how can I get byte[] out of that?

Answer (score 1):

I am late here but this might help someone. I was facing same issue i was always getting -1 value, when ever i was trying get the content length.

previously i was using below method to get content length.

```
long totalByte=connection.getContentLength();
```

Below fixed my problem:-

```
long totalByte=connection.getHeaderFieldLong("Content-Length",-1);
```