# My file downloader occur error suddenly

Tags: android, download, apk

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        URL imgurl;
        int Read;
        try {
            imgurl = new URL(ServerUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imgurl.openConnection();
            int len = conn.getContentLength();
            Log.d("check", "ContentLength:" + len);
            Log.d("check", "ServerUrl:" + ServerUrl);
            Log.d("check", "LocalPath:" + LocalPath);
            byte[] tmpByte = new byte[len];
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            File file = new File(LocalPath);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            for (;;) {
                Read = is.read(tmpByte);
                if (Read <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                fos.write(tmpByte, 0, Read);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            conn.disconnect();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            ut.CalltoAlertDialog_ok(getString(R.string.alert), getString(R.string.setting_skin_downloadfail));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ut.CalltoAlertDialog_ok(getString(R.string.alert), getString(R.string.setting_skin_downloadfail));
        }

        mAfterDown.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
```

This is file download source.

This code prints error "NegativeArraySizeException" from here

```
byte[] tmpByte = new byte[len];
```

So, I checked len's value.
len's value was -1.

But..
When i created yesterday, This code was not print error.

I have 2 apk file.
The apk created yesterday is not a problem. Even now this apk is no problem.
But, The apk created today is problem.

I did not modify anything.

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Variables should start with a lower-case letter. Confusing otherwise.

Comment: If the code worked (exaclty same code) then it seems like your problem is on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imgurl.openConnection();
  int len = conn.getContentLength();
```

Read documentation about the [getContentLength](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength()) method

> Returns the content length in bytes specified by the response header
>   field content-length or -1 if this field is not set.
>
> Returns the value of the response header field content-length.

So this case that getContentLength returned -1 seems to have happened to you. Then you use this -1 to set your Array size. => Exception thrown

Check the solution of this [question about getContentLength returning -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439829/urlconnection-getcontentlength-returns-1), maybe you will have to do something similar.

But at least you will have to check that `len > 0` before setting your array size