# Content length is -1 when trying to request an HTTPS page using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to execute an HTTPS equest in Java using HttpsURLConnection. The problem that I have is that content length is "-1" which is shouldn't be.

I have tried different https pages, and they all return -1 as         content length

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        String realURL = "https://facebook.com";
        URL myurl = null;
        try {
            myurl = new URL(realURL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();


        System.out.println (        conn.getContentLength()
    );
        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thankful for all the help I can get, thank you.

Comment: check conn.responseCode/.responseMessage?

Comment: Always check the Javadoc first if you get a value you don't expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URLConnection.getContentLength() returns -1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439829/urlconnection-getcontentlength-returns-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc of `URLConnection.getContentLength()` says:

> Returns: the content length of the resource that this connection's URL
>   references, -1 if the content length is not known, or if the content
>   length is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Facebook does not respond with a `content-length` header therefore you receive a -1.