# How to get Content-Length from response headers in CN1?

Tags: codenameone

I implemented [this](https://gist.github.com/codenameone/3c9ffaef41f523426552) but the response headers don't include `Content-Length`, even though I make sure the server replies that bit specifically. I also verified the response outside CN1 and it includes Content-Length. The full list of headers captured in `ReadHeaders` is (as seen from Android): `null,Alt-Svc,Cache-Control,Connection,Content-Type,Date,ETag,Server,Transfer-Encoding,Vary,X-Android-Received-Millis,X-Android-Response-Source,X-Android-Selected-Protocol,X-Android-Sent-Millis,X-Cloud-Trace-Context,X-Powered-By`. Right now to estimate download sizes I (1) call endpoint to get total size (2) call endpoint to get actual download and use `NetworkManager` progress listener, but it would be nice to be able to track progress with only one request (by using `Content-Length`). The vanilla `RequestBuilder` doesn't expose response headers so a direct usage of `ConnectionRequest` with `readHeaders` is needed. But the `Content-Length` is missing from `getHeaderFieldNames`

Note:

Comment: Why aren't you using `getContentLength()` ?

Comment: That was my first attempt (returns 0). I ended up implementing a native call with OKHTTP 3 that does work. I will copy the code below... something must be different from CN1's implementation. Could also be related to different server settings, although I did try all different values for Transfer-Encoding header and still didn't work

Comment: We use this method to show progress indicators etc. so I'm pretty sure it works. It would return -1 if the value isn't set so if it returned 0 it means something went wrong. Is the URL redirecting?

Comment: sry, I should have said -1. It might be related to my server (node.js) settings rather than CN1. I can't figure it out...

Comment: You don't need to do this in the read headers just when you read the response. That's where the content length is available. If you get 200 then content length should be available too.

Comment: Isn't the response only available after everything has been fetched? (so can't track progress)

Comment: No. Response code is a header so it's available once you're connected before fetching the actual data. Also see this: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/SliderBridge.java

Comment: Just finished testing this. So the issue is on Android, where `getLength()` always returns -1. The simulator works fine. Shall I open an issue?

Comment: Do you have a test case for this that we can run?
If so please do.

Comment: Done. https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3331

Comment: Might this be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440136/756809

Comment: Got to the bottom of this. I updated the answer and closed the issue on Github. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this wasn't working is because by default Android/CN1 sends a request with the header `Accept-Enconding`:`gzip`. This returns a chunked response that doesn't include the length header. I can't guarantee that this behavior matches every server response, but it does in my case (Node.js + Express)

To force a server to return a non-chunked response, set the header to "compress", "identity", or "deflate"

Example:

```
Rest.post(url).header("Accept-Encoding", "compress").fetchAsJsonMap(resp -> {...
```